# stat to fill details of file in structure passed by reference

Tags: c++, linux, stat

I have a function which takes struct by reference and fills the details of file in it, but when I compile I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘stat::stat(char*&, stat*)’
         stat (buffer,&buf);
```

Can someone please let know how should I pass the buffer to stat?

Here is the code:

```
void filedetails(char *path, int pathlen ,struct stat &buf){
        char *buffer;
        strncpy(buffer,path,pathlen-1);
        buffer[pathlen-1]='\0';
        stat (buffer,&buf);
}
```

it is being called as follows:

```
struct stat st_buf;
char path[256];
//path gets filled here and is manually null terminated//
path[256] = '\0';
filedetails(path,256,st_buf);
```

Comment: You also have another problem of `buffer` not being initialized.

Comment: There's probably something more in your code. The basic [code seems to work](http://ideone.com/9yk7pd). What's suspicious is that the compiler is complaining about `stat::stat`. Do you have a class called `stat` by any chance?

Comment: I have to assume that you went to this trouble because you are expecting to call this with a `path` which is not nul-terminated?  Because otherwise, you might just as well call `stat()` directly: `stat(path, &st_buf);`

Comment: @ViteFalcon, there is no other class named stat

Comment: @JohnHascall After null terminating also I am still getting the same error

Comment: That was not an answer, just a comment.  Your biggest problem is you need to allocate buffer... `buffer = malloc(pathlen + 1);` (and then `free(buffer);` at the end.  As for the `stat::stat...` business, I have no ideas there... sorry

Comment: Try prefixing your `stat` call with a scope resolution operator, like this: `::stat(buffer, &buf);` If it works, then you have a name collision.